# Jq, combine element in array

Tags: json, key, jq

I have a json file like this

```
[
  "public-policy-routing/0",
  "public-policy-routing/1",
  "public-policy-routing/5",
  "public-policy-routing/7",
  "public-policy-routing/10"
]
```

since the element has pattern "key/values" where only values part differ I want to reduce the output to something like this

```
{ "public-policy-routing" : [0,1,5,7,10] }
```

any idea how to achieve above using jq ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be using `reduce` on the array elements. Split at the slash, destructure the resulting array into a key and value variable, then add the value as an array to the field with the key name:

```bash
jq 'reduce (.[]/"/") as [$k,$v] ({}; .[$k] += [$v])'
```

```json
{
  "public-policy-routing": [
    "0",
    "1",
    "5",
    "7",
    "10"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6bS1BQXm-8i)

If you wanted numbers instead of strings, convert the values using `tonumber`:

```bash
jq 'reduce (.[]/"/") as [$k,$v] ({}; .[$k] += [$v | tonumber])'
```

```json
{
  "public-policy-routing": [
    0,
    1,
    5,
    7,
    10
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IuWVODcM86M)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mildly robust solution:

```
 def ton: try tonumber catch .;
 def keysplit: index("/") as $i
   | if $i then [.[:$i],  (.[$i+1:]|ton) ] else [., ""]  end;

 reduce ( .[]|keysplit ) as [$k,$v] ({}; .[$k] += [$v] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a robust solution that works with arbitrary strings by [grouping them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73893818/112968):

```
def group(f): group_by(f) | map({key:first|f, value:.}) | from_entries;
map(. / "/") | group(first) | map_values(map(last|tonumber))
```

or without a custom function:

```
map(. / "/")
| group_by(first)
| map({key:first|first, value:map(last|tonumber)})
| from_entries
```